# Combining Statements Togeher

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering if it is possible to combine 2 if statements with else statements together. One if - else  is for > then 99 days and the other is for > ie 9. Here are the 2 statements.

**> 99 Days Code**

```
function init(elem, options) {
 elem.addClass('countdownHolder');

// Time left
 var left = Math.floor((options.timestamp - (new Date())) / 1000);
 // Number of days left
 var d = Math.floor(left / days);

// Creating the markup inside the container
 $.each(['Days', 'Hours', 'Minutes', 'Seconds'], function (i) {
 if (this == 'Days' && d > 99) {
 $('<span class="count' + this + '">').html(
 '<span class="position">\
 <span class="digit static">0</span>\
 </span>\
 <span class="position">\
 <span class="digit static">0</span>\
 </span>\
 <span class="position">\
 <span class="digit static">0</span>\
 </span>'
 ).appendTo(elem);
 }
 else {
 $('<span class="count' + this + '">').html(
 '<span class="position">\
 <span class="digit static">0</span>\
 </span>\
 <span class="position">\
 <span class="digit static">0</span>\
 </span>'
 ).appendTo(elem);
 }
 if (this != "Seconds") {
 elem.append('<span class="countDiv countDiv' + i + '"></span>');
 }
 });

}
```

**> ie 9 Code**

```
var ie = (function(){

var undef,
    v = 3,
    div = document.createElement('div'),
    all = div.getElementsByTagName('i');

while (
    div.innerHTML = '<!--[if gt IE ' + (++v) + ']><i></i><![endif]-->',
    all[0]
);

return v > 4 ? v : undef;

}());

function init(elem, options){
    elem.addClass('countdownHolder');

    // Creating the markup inside the container
    $.each(['Days','Hours','Minutes','Seconds'],function(i){
        if (ie>9){
        $('<span class="count'+this+'">').html(
            '<span class="position">\
                <span class="digit static">0</span>\
            </span>\
            <span class="position">\
                <span class="digit static">0</span>\
            </span>'
        ).appendTo(elem);
        }else{
            $('<span class="count'+this+'">' +
            '<span class="position">' +
                '<span class="digit static">0</span>' +
            '</span>' +
            '<span class="position">' +
                '<span class="digit static">0</span>' +
            '</span>' +
        '</span>').appendTo(elem);
        }
        if(this!="Seconds"){
            elem.append('<span class="countDiv countDiv'+i+'"></span>');
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Can i see right or are you using just two same content in "if (ie>9)" part.. ie can be any and same code is executed?

Comment: why do you even need different versions? All I see is a class difference and that can be managed with css...or just remove the class with jQuery `removeClass`

Comment: The reason I need different version if I'm not mistaking versions of IE lower then 9 doesn't understand the .html so instead of .html you use a +. If I'm wrong please let me know, this is just from reading on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

```
switch (true) {
  case d > 99: ...; break
  case ie > 9: ...; break
  default: ... /* this is your "else" */
}
```